# change not reflecting in .master from html in master page sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, master-page

i need to add a user control in master page in 2013 desinger. I have checked out file and added this below line:

```
<!--SPM:<%@Register TagPrefix="LogOut" TagName="LogOutUserControl" Src="~/_controltemplates/15/UC_LogOut/LogOut.ascx" %>-->
```

Now this should reflect in .master file also but after refreshing also i cant see this control there in master page. Also did checked in then also cant see this control. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added your control. You've just registered it.
After the registration you need to add another line like so:

```
 <!--SPM:<LogOut:LogOutUserControl id="LlgOutUserControl" runat="server" />-->
```

Comment: i have added control it is showing error of reference because it has not yet been added in .master file. First it should be register there in .master file

Comment: can you add a <h1>TEST</h1> tag somewhere in .html file and see if .master file gets updated?

Comment: yes i tried same it is showing there but only register line is not showing

Comment: Can you create a test page in /_layouts/15/? Add this registration to this page and see what happens.